# Quasicompact? Why the distinction?

Tags: general-topology, terminology, compactness

What is the reason that some topologists use quasicompact? Why is the distinction made? quasi means "not really", so why use this terminology?

Comment: Because for some reason they want to limit the term *compact* to compact Hausdorff spaces and still need some term for compact spaces that aren’t Hausdorff. I find it mildly annoying, but I gather that it’s pretty standard in algebraic geometry, for instance. I believe that the Bourbaki school is to blame for it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, besides Engelking's General Topology, are there any recent book on general topology that uses this termination?

Comment: @Paulo: I simply don’t know; I’ve not actually seen any reasonably high-level topology books more recent than Engelking and Willard.

Comment: Thank you @BrianM.Scott. It seemed like a silly thing to do since it really does not save that many letters.

Comment: I think that maybe it's because quasi-compact subsets of the non-Hausdorff spaces don't have the same good properties that quasi-compact subsets of Hausdorff spaces do. For instance, quasi-compact subsets of non-Hausdorff spaces need not be closed.